# nuxt 3 index.vue does not render the content as SSR

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

am using Nuxt 3 and I have set up my own API using the Server Directory as shown in the documentation here. However, I am facing an issue where the content of my `index.vue` file in the page folder is not being rendered as SSR.

Here is my directory structure:

```
--page
  --index.vue
```

I want `index.vue` to be the main page of my website, but the content is not being rendered as SSR. I tried moving the entire content to a new page called `[any name].vue` and the same data was rendered as SSR.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout name="moviedetails">
    <v-container>
      <v-card class="my-4" color="transparent" variant="flat">
        <main-news-slider class="mt-4" />
        <v-container>
          <v-card color="transparent" flat>
            <div id="AADIV33"></div>
          </v-card>
        </v-container>
        <!-- <ClientOnly> -->
        <IGNSlider :data="ignIndex.data" />
        <!-- </ClientOnly> -->
        <AnimeSlider :season="getCurrentSeason()" />
        <v-card-actions class="justify-center my-4">
          <v-btn-toggle
            color="primary"
            mandatory
            density="compact"
            v-model="trendTime"
            rounded="xl"
          >
            <v-btn value="week" size="small" density="compact"
              >هذا الأسبوع</v-btn
            >
            <v-btn value="day" size="small" density="compact">اليوم</v-btn>
          </v-btn-toggle>
        </v-card-actions>
        <swiper-trends-slider
          :swiperData="trendTime == 'day' ? todayTrendsData : weekTrendsData"
        >
        </swiper-trends-slider>
      </v-card>
      <v-locale-provider rtl>
        <v-card
          v-for="genres in allGenres"
          class="my-4"
          color="transparent"
          variant="flat"
        >
          <v-card-title class="mt-4"> {{ genres?.item?.title }} </v-card-title>
          <swiper-geners-sliders
            :swiperGenederData="genres?.data?.results"
            :swiperBreakPoints="genersBreakPoints"
            :mediaDataId="genres?.item"
          >
          </swiper-geners-sliders>
        </v-card>
      </v-locale-provider>
    </v-container>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<script setup>
import { getCurrentSeason } from "~~/common/commonFuntions";
import IGNSlider from "~~/components/IGNSlider.vue";

const trendTime = ref("day");

const genersBreakPoints = ref({
  640: {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 20,
  },
  768: {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 20,
  },
  1024: {
    slidesPerView: 6,
    spaceBetween: 20,
  },
});

const { data: todayTrendsData } = await useFetch(
  `/api/trendslider/day?type=day`
);
const { data: weekTrendsData } = await useFetch(
  `/api/trendslider/day?type=week`
);

const randid = function generateRandomId() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000) + 100000 + "";
};

const { data: ignIndex } = await useFetch(`/api/ign/home?${randid}=${randid}`);
console.log(ignIndex);
const { data: allGenres } = await useFetch("/api/genres");

const returnMainPaegAds = () => {
  /* header_ads_section */ var k = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
    ca = k.split(";"),
    psc = "";
  ca;
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == " ") c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf("adcapban") == 0)
      psc +=
        (psc == "" ? "" : ",") + c.replace("adcapban", "").replace("=", ",");
  }
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src =
    "https://adsmanager.trexqr.com/ser.php?t=AADIV33" +
    String.fromCharCode(38) +
    "f=33" +
    String.fromCharCode(38) +
    "psc=" +
    psc;
  s;
  return s.src;
};

const showScript = ref(false);

const nuxt = useNuxtApp();

nuxt.hook("page:start", () => {
  showScript.value = false;
});

nuxt.hook("page:finish", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    showScript.value = true;
  }, 1000);
});

const route = useRoute();

useHead({
  script: [
    {
      src: () => (showScript.value == true ? returnMainPaegAds() : ""),
      tagPosition: "head", // valid options are: 'head' | 'bodyClose' | 'bodyOpen'
    },
  ],
});

// definePageMeta({
//   layout: "moviedetails",
//   key: (route) => route.fullPath,
// });
</script>

<style>
.ck-content * {
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

and this is my nuxt.config file

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config

import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";
import { createResolver } from "@nuxt/kit";

const { resolve } = createResolver(import.meta.url);

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  modules: ["nuxt-swiper", '@pinia/nuxt', 'nuxt-delay-hydration', "nuxt-lodash"],
  delayHydration: {
    idleCallbackTimeout: 2000
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    TMDBKEY: process.env.NUXT_TMDBKEY,
    SCRIPT_KEY: process.env.NUXT_SCRIPT,
    PPKEY: "123",
    public: {
      TMDBKEY: "*****",
    },
  },
  css: [
    "vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass",
    "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
    "@/assets/main.scss",
    "@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css"
  ],
  build: {
    transpile: ["vuetify"],
  },

  vite: {
    define: {
      "process.env.DEBUG": false,
    },
  },
  app: {
    head: {
      titleTemplate: "%s - Aflam.vip",
      title: "Aflam.vip",
      meta: [
        { charset: "utf-8" },
        {
          name: "viewport",
          content:
            "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0",
        },
        { name: "msapplication-TileImage", content: "telephone=no" },
        { name: "propeller", content: "*****" },
      ],
      script: [
      ],
      style: [],
      noscript: []
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  imports: {
    dirs: ['./stores'],
  },
  pinia: {
    autoImports: ['defineStore', 'acceptHMRUpdate'],
  },
});
```

Comment: ensure components   you use are actually supported in SSR

Comment: how so? 
the same code work in new router
@ProblemSlover